# Rx Android - wait for server response

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I use RxJava and Retrofit in an Android app to get data from server. I have test activity with this code.

```
    String text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        viewMenu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_menu);
        tabMenu.initTabBar(viewMenu, this);
        CapabilitiesHolder.createIfNotExist().getCapabilities().subscribe(this::handleResponse, RestErrorHandler::handle);
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    private void handleResponse(CapabilitiesResponse capabilitiesResponse) {
        if (capabilitiesResponse.isSuccess()) {
            text = capabilitiesResponse.getSupportedCurrencies().get(0).getDescription();
        } else {
            RestErrorHandler.handle(null, capabilitiesResponse);
        }
    }
```

And a Singleton class to contain data from server during whole lifecycle of the app.

```
public class CapabilitiesHolder {


    private static CapabilitiesHolder mInstance = null;

    private CapabilitiesResponse capabilities;


    public static CapabilitiesHolder createIfNotExist() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new CapabilitiesHolder();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private CapabilitiesHolder() {
        requestCapabilities();
    }

    public Observable<CapabilitiesResponse> getCapabilities() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> capabilities);
    }

    private CompositeSubscription compositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();

    private void requestCapabilities() {
        Observable<CapabilitiesResponse> o = RestServiceFactory.get().getServerCapabilities();
        compositeSubscription.add(o.subscribe(this::handleResponse, RestErrorHandler::handle));
    }

    private void handleResponse(CapabilitiesResponse capabilitiesResponse) {
        if (capabilitiesResponse.isSuccess()) {
            capabilities = capabilitiesResponse;
        } else {
            RestErrorHandler.handle(null, capabilitiesResponse);
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        mInstance = null;
        mInstance = new CapabilitiesHolder();
    }
}
```

So when my test Activity created first time, and immediately calls for `CapabilitiesHolder.createIfNotExist().getCapabilities()` the tost is empty, because data in response needs some time to be loaded. When `onCreate` called a bit later, everything's ok.

The question is, ho can I make (Using RxJava?) `getCapabilities()` method wait for response from server, before being called.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - don't block the UI thread and wait for anything.

Move your Toast into the method that handles the response

```
 private void handleResponse(CapabilitiesResponse capabilitiesResponse) {
    if (capabilitiesResponse.isSuccess()) {
        text = capabilitiesResponse.getSupportedCurrencies().get(0).getDescription();
        // Toast here 
    } else {
        RestErrorHandler.handle(null, capabilitiesResponse);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. But as I mentioned, this is a test Activity, So Toast will be removed at all. The core question was about how can I make `CapabilitiesHolder.createIfNotExist().getCapabilities()` this to return result when it's ready, instead of returning `null` after first call.

Comment: It doesn't return null. The getCapabilities method does not (and should not) block. The request has simply not finished at the point of your Toast method.

Comment: You have your callback handler set the response. Doesn't matter if you are Toasting or updating your UI. That's what I'm saying

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to rebuild your class `CapabilitiesHolder` class. If you want to use that holder like that you should not request any data inside constructor. Also blocking UI thread is **bad practice**.

```
private CapabilitiesHolder() {
    //empty
}

public Observable<CapabilitiesResponse> getCapabilities() {
    if(capabilities!=null){
        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> capabilities);
    } else {
        return RestServiceFactory.get()
                .getServerCapabilities()
                .doOnNext(capabilitiesResponse -> capabilities = capabilitiesResponse);
    }
}
```